# App Status is "Pending Contracts" after renewal of Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My Apple Developer program membership is expired, so my App has been removed from the App Store.

And I already renewed today, but the App status in iTunes Connect still shows **`pending contracts`** like the following picture:

[image: Pending Contracts]

What should I do after renewals? Should I submit the App again?

Answer (score 24):

Apple won't publish apps until you've accepted the contracts.

- Log in to iTunes Connect.
- Go to Contracts, Tax and Banking.
- Add the necessary info there. Your app will then be automatically approved.

Comment: You means add contracts Information , Bank Information and Tax Information ?  Why I need to add these ? I didn't add these information at first time.

Comment: All the correct information is there so nothing to update but all my paid apps stay as Pending agreement, this is not right over a week since I renewed my membership and nowhere to go

Comment: Apple keeps shuffling stuff about. It's now "Agreements, Tax, and Banking" under App Store Connect > My Apps

Answer (score 7):

When your status is `Active (Pending User Info)`.

Go to `Agreements, Tax, and Banking` and `View` for paid apps. In that page you need to add contact for `Senior Management`, `Financial`, `Technical`, `Legal`, `Marketing` and you are done.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have applied for renewal of contract, then Apple will send one code within 2 business days. You need to click on the activation code and enter it to activate account. Once you activate your account, the application state will automatically change from Pending contract to "Ready for sale"

No need to submit application again...!!!

Answer (score 3):

We hit this problem and tried a number of methods as found to fix it but got nowehere.  It appears we had paid the renewal in the developer center but for some reason the update was not synchronised with itunes connect.

A quick call to iOS developer center on one of the numbers listed on the following page and the issue was fixed by the support person within a couple of minutes.

https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/

Answer (score 2):

Login to your [apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/account) and you would need to clear any notifications like the one shown here.

[image]

Comment: re: this particular error: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372563/there-is-no-credit-debit-card-on-the-apple-online-store-associated-with-your-app/

Answer (score 1):

- Login to iTunesConnect.
- Go to Contracts, Tax and Banking.
- Fill in your info.